DbgHelp issue in 64bit Release version
I am using Dbgelp in MFC based application. Everything works fine 64bit Debug version. In 64 bit Release it works fine when the Optimization Settings in Project is Disabled. But if Optimization settings is ON then it crashed again. I mentioned in below code where the error happens. Can anyone help me out?
auto CALLBACK EnumSymbolsCallback( SYMBOL_INFO* pptSymbolInfo, ULONG piSymbolSize, void* ppvUserContext ) -> BOOL
{       

    const T_EnumSymbols* lpkSymbols{ static_cast<const T_EnumSymbols*>( ppvUserContext ) };

    std::vector<std::string>* lpkParameters{ lpkSymbols->m_pkParameters };
    
    const STACKFRAME64* lptStackFrame{ lpkSymbols->m_ptStackFrame };

    
    if( pptSymbolInfo != nullptr &&
            lpkParameters != nullptr    )
    {
        if( pptSymbolInfo->Flags & SYMFLAG_PARAMETER )
        {
            if( pptSymbolInfo->Tag == ::SymTagData )
            {               
                    
                // ISSUE HERE   
                void* lpvValueAddress{ ( void* )( lptStackFrame->AddrStack.Offset + pptSymbolInfo->Address ) };             
                
            }
        }
    }
}

I read that in 64bit without optimization the First Four Parameters are in RCX, RDX, R8, and R9 Registers and other are on Stack. If so then how to get symbols values from those Registers?

Please provide a [mre].

You are assuming the flags have SYMFLAG_FRAMEREL set.
You need to handle:

SYMFLAG_FRAMEREL
SYMFLAG_REGREL
SYMFLAG_REGISTER

so something like this:
if( pptSymbolInfo->Flags & SYMFLAG_FRAMEREL ) {
   use -> value == *(lptStackFrame->AddrStack.Offset + pptSymbolInfo->Address)
} else if ( pptSymbolInfo->Flags & SYMFLAG_REGREL ) {
   use -> value == *(threadContextRegisters[static_cast<CV_HREG_e>(pptSymbolInfo->Register)] + pptSymbolInfo->Address)
} else if ( pptSymbolInfo->Flags & SYMFLAG_REGISTER) {
   use -> value == threadContextRegisters[static_cast<CV_HREG_e>(pptSymbolInfo->Register)]
}

threadContextRegisters references something that points to the thread current context register values, you need to sort this out yourself like your lpkSymbols->m_ptStackFrame stack frame pointer.
e.g. std::map<CV_HREG_e, ulong> threadContextRegisters
